# Use column of list values and apply as keys to another column of dictionary values on pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

Say I have a dataframe called "result" that consists of two columns, one that has list values and the other has dictionary values like this:

```
List_Column                           
[06052, 06710, 06513, 06604]              

Program_Dict_Column
{'06710': 'Program1', '06604': 'Program2', '06513': 'Program2', '06106': 'Program3', '06052': 'Program4', '06082': 'Program5'}
```

I'm trying to use the list column as keys (each element in list) to map to the dictionary column to create a new column that is the output values.

```
Desired Sample Output:
['Program4','Program1','Program2','Program2']
```

I can make it work for single cases by doing the following:
example for index = 2

```
[result.Program_Dict_Column[2][i] for i in result.List_Column[2]]
```

But I can't seem to make this work for all dataframe values.

I've tried:

1.making a function then using lambda to apply:

```
def get_values(dics, lists):
    for k,v in dics.items():
        return [v[i] for i in lists]


result["Desired_Programs"] = result.apply(lambda x: get_values(x.Program_Dict_Column, x.List_Column),axis=1)
```

however I get an error: TypeError: string indices must be integers

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you provide a sample output?

Comment: yes, added a desired sample output above. thanks.

Comment: In general, if you're storing things like lists and dictionaries inside of a DataFrame, you're going to find yourself fighting `pandas` rather than benefiting from it. Though it's not the question you asked, I'd encourage you to consider reworking your data somewhat (e.g., `List Column` could be a `pd.Series` and `Program_Dict_Column` a `pd.DataFrame`)

Comment: Are you trying to create a column where all the values in the column maps to the `Program_Dict_Column` mapping?

Comment: yeah, basically taking the values from List_Column and (using them as keys) mapping to Program_Dict_Column to get dictionary values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your list consists of numbers and cannot be directly used as keys of your dict, which are strings - though a converison is simple and I will not get to that part

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'List_Column':[['06052', '06710', '06513', '06604']], 'Program_Dict_Column':[{'06710': 'Program1', '06604': 'Program2', '06513': 'Program2', '06106': 'Program3', '06052': 'Program4', '06082': 'Program5'}
]})

def getValue(row):
    return [row['Program_Dict_Column'][x] for x in row['List_Column']]
df['result']=df.apply(getValue,axis=1)
df['result']
```

Comment: this is exactly what I was trying to do. thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `explode()` and `apply` to get the result:

```
df.explode('list_col').apply(lambda x: x['dict_col'][x.list_col], axis=1)\
  .reset_index(drop=True)
```

Output:

```
0    Program4
1    Program1
2    Program2
3    Program2
dtype: object
```